# One to Many relationship in DynamoDB

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following data I want to save in a DynamoDB and I'm not quite sure how to do it in the most smart way.

My clients are connecting to my app via websocket and then "subscribe" to one ticker. But one ticker can have multiple clients subscribed to it.

The problem is: I need to be able to query both ways. My app has to query 1. to which ticker a specific client is subscribed (for example for reconnection purposes or to handle the disconnect script) and 2. which clients are connected to a ticker (to send infos to these clients)

Do I need to use two tables for that or is it possible in one?

Im thankful for every answer. Right now I'm using two tables, one with the columns connectionId (PK), ticker
and one with ticker(PK) and clients

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could follow the [`Single-Table Design`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-modeling-nosql-B.html) and design your table in the following way:

```
[
    {
        "PK": "SUBSCRIBER#USER_123",
        "SK": "TICKER#TICKER_987",
        [...]
    },
    {
        "PK": "SUBSCRIBER#USER_123",
        "SK": "TICKER#TICKER_654",
        [...]
    },
    {
        "PK": "TICKER#TICKER_999",
        "SK": "CONNECTED#USER_123",
        [...]
    },
    {
        "PK": "TICKER#TICKER_999",
        "SK": "CONNECTED#USER_456",
        [...]
    }
]
```

The query part could look like that

> 1. to which ticker a specific client is subscribed

```
{
    TableName: 'TABLE',
    KeyConditionExpression: 'PK = :PK',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':PK': `SUBSCRIBER#${userId}`
    }
}
```

> 2. which clients are connected to a ticker

```
{
    TableName: 'TABLE',
    KeyConditionExpression: 'PK = :PK',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':PK': `TICKER#${tickerId}`
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Would that be a better solution than ceating a global secondary index? Someone else suggested that

Comment: @Janv I guess it's a matter of taste. The write and read capacity units remain the same, so from the cost perspective it doesn't really matter. But for me the "killer" argument is "eventual consistency". As soon as you create a GSI (global secondary index), the GSI is "eventual consistent", if you can live/work with it you could also go with GSI.